# D3 Format Days to Years

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an X Axis that is currently displaying the number of days based on the range of the data. Because the number of days are so large, it would be helpful to create a custom formatter to show the days in number of years, instead.

Here is my current X Axis and Scale:

```
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
        .range([padding, w-padding])
        .nice();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(5);
```

My domain is currently something like `[0, 9,000]` days. I want these to display these in years or months. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with relative time, where only you know the units, you'll have to write a [custom formatter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_tickFormat). Maybe something like this will work, but you'll have to figure out how elegant you want your function to be. I wrote a quick "no-thought-added" formatter, but you'll probably want to put some thought into it:

```
var ...,
max = xRange.domain()[1],
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .tickFormat(function (days) {
      if (max < 50) {
        return d3.format("2.1f")(days) + " d";
      }
      else if (max >= 50 && max < 100) {
        return d3.format("2.1f")(days/7) + " w";
      }
      else if (max >= 100 && max < 500) {
        return d3.format("2.1f")(days/(365/12)) + " m";
      }
      else if (max >= 500){
        return d3.format("2.1f")(days/365) + " y";
      } 
    } 
  )
```

here is a simple, ugly, demo to show this: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJsMLmtRQjBjWGLPRM7I?p=preview)

change the data points to see it switch scales.

Comment: Okay, so you right your own custom formatter function. I just assumed that D3 had a library for converting day/week/month units.

Comment: d3 has good handling of time when you are talking about absolute time, but it's not really quite in d3's scope to convert every type of unit, but it can easily take in a custom function or another library that can handle conversion and formatting. For instance, you could use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/human-format) to handle the formatting.